# finding simple probabilities of a dice throw

Tags: probability

I am not sure how to solve this question. Would appreciate your help:

$4$ normal dice are thrown:

a)  If we obtain at least $2$ even results, what are the chances that between the $4$ results, there's at least one result who is equal to 6?

b)  If $4$ even (not odd) results were obtained, what is the probability of them being larger than 3?

My attempt:

For one die: $s=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}, e=\{2,4,6\}$. Since we're talking about $4$ dice, then $|s_1|=|s|^4=6^4=204$ and $|e_1|=|e|^4=3^4=81$

so for a), we'll define $|e_2|=|e|^2=9$ (we need $2$ even results at least). the odds of obtaining at least one six from $4$ dices is $\frac{1}{24}$, so to calculate it I need to sum $\frac{9}{204}+\frac{1}{24}$ as in the addition of two events? or to divide?

b)  odds of obtaining $4$ even results are $\frac{|e_1|}{|s_1|}=\frac{27}{68}$, and to assure that all of the results are larger than 3 $e_3=\{4,5,6\}$ and we need $|e_3|^4=81$ (again) divided by $|s^4|$.

I'm doing something wrong here, can someone please show me how to solve it correctly? also would appreciate learning the correct notation and writing so I can learn to make it correct and more aesthetic.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Die is singular; dice is plural; dices is the third person singular form of the verb to dice, meaning to cut into small cubes.

Comment: It may be useful to note that $6^4 = 1296$, not $204$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Four normal dice are thrown.  If we obtain at least two even results, what are the chances that among the four results, there is at least one $6$?

Our sample space consists of those cases in which $2$, $3$, or $4$ of the results are even.

Each die has probability $1/2$ of showing an even result.  The probability that exactly $k$ of the four dice will show an even result is given by the [Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).
$$\Pr(X = k) = \binom{4}{k}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^4$$

Clearly, we cannot obtain a 6 on a die that shows an odd result. If a die shows an even result, the probability of obtaining a 6 is $1/3$ since a 2, 4, or 6 is equally likely to appear.  Therefore, the probability of not obtaining a 6 on a die that shows an even result is $1 - 1/3 = 2/3$.  The probability of not obtaining a 6 on $k$ dice that each show an even result is $(2/3)^k$, which means the probability of obtaining at least one 6 on $k$ dice that each show an even result is 
$$1 - \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^k$$

Let $S$ be the event that at least one six appears.  Let $X = k$ be the event that exactly $k$ of the dice show an even result.  Then the probability that at least one six appears if at least two dice show an even result is 
\begin{align*}
\Pr(S \mid X \geq 2) & = \frac{\Pr(S \cap X \geq 2)}{\Pr(X \geq 2)}\\
                     & = \frac{\Pr(S \cap X = 2) + \Pr(S \cap X = 3) + \Pr(X \cap X = 4)}{\Pr(X = 2) + \Pr(X = 3) + \Pr(X = 4)}\\ 
                     & = \frac{\Pr(S \mid X = 2)\Pr(X = 2) + \Pr(S \mid X = 3)\Pr(X = 3) + \Pr(S \mid X = 4)\Pr(X = 4)}{\binom{4}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^4 + \binom{4}{3}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^4 + \binom{4}{4}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^4}\\
& = \frac{\left[1 - \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^2\right]\binom{4}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^4 + \left[1 - \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^3\right]\binom{4}{3}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^4 + \left[1 - \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^4\right]\binom{4}{4}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^4}{\binom{4}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^4 + \binom{4}{3}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^4 + \binom{4}{4}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^4}
\end{align*}

> If four even results are obtained, what is the probability of them being greater than 3?

Since each die shows an even result, the possible results on a given die are 2, 4, or 6.  Of these three equally likely events, two are greater than 3.  Hence, the probability that a die showing an even result exhibits a result greater than 3 is $2/3$.  The probability that all four dice will show a result greater than 3 result given that each die shows an even result is 
$$\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^4$$

Comment: My initial answer was incorrect.  I computed the probability that a six was obtained and at least two of the four dice showed an even result, that is, I calculated $\Pr(S \cap X \geq 2)$, where $S$ is the event that at least one six is obtained and $X = k$ is the event that exactly $k$ of the four dice exhibit an even number.  However, we want $\Pr(S \mid X \geq 2)$, the conditional probability that a six is obtained if at least two of the four dice exhibit an even number, so we must divide that probability by the probability that at least two dice exhibit an even number.  Now corrected.